# Android - Disable SwitchPreference from changing state but get click response to launch dialog?

Tags: android, switchpreference

If I disable using `setEnabled(false)` the switch is (1) set to off and (2) I don't get a response from the `OnClickListener` to launch a dialog.

Edit: In this case, I don't want the switch to automatically switch from on to off.

Has anyone dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to use `setChecked(true)` inside the `OnPreferenceClickListener` callback then launch the dialog.

Note: this did not work inside of the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` callback.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

For those who want the code :

```
if (!BuildConfig.FULL_VERSION) {
            SwitchPreferenceCompat preference = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_notifications_service_key));
            preference.setDefaultValue(false);
            preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    ((SwitchPreferenceCompat) preference).setChecked(false);
                    new ProFeatureDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "PRO_FEATURE_TAG");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```